# How to keep multiple independent celery queues?

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to keep multiple celery queues with different tasks and workers in the same redis database. Really just a convenience issue of only wanting one redis server rather than two on my machine.

I followed the celery tutorial docs verbatim, as it as the only way to get it to work for me. Now when I try to duplicate everything with slightly tweaked names/queues, it keeps erroring out.

Note - I'm a newish to Python and Celery, which is obviously part of the problem. I'm not sure which parts are named "task/tasks" as a name vs special words.

My condensed version of docs:
Run `celery -A tasks worker` to spawn the workers.
tasks.py contains task code with `celery = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost')` to connect to Celery and `@task()` above my functions that I want to delay.

Within my program for queueing tasks...

```
from tasks import do_work
do_work.delay()
```

So given all of the above, what are the steps I need to take to turn this into two types of tasks that run independently on separate queues and workers? For example, blue_tasks and red_tasks?

I've tried changing all instances of tasks to blue_tasks or red_tasks. However, when I queue blue_tasks, the red_tasks workers I've started up start trying to work on them.

I read about default queues and such, so I tried this code, which didn't work:

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'red'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('red', Exchange('red'), routing_key='red'),
)
```

As a side note, I don't understand why `celery worker` errors out with celery attempting to connect to a default amqp instance, while `celery -A tasks worker` tells celery to connect to Redis. What task code is `celery worker` attempting to run on the worker if nothing has been specified?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

By default everything goes into a default queue named `celery` (and this is what `celery worker` will process if no queue is specified)

So say you have your `do_work` task function in `django_project_root/myapp/tasks.py`.

You could configure the `do_work` task to live in it's own queue like so:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'myproject.tasks.do_work': {'queue': 'red'},
}
```

Then run a worker using `celery worker -Q red` and it will only process things in that queue (another worker invoked with `celery worker` will only pickup things in the default queue)

The [task routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) section in the documentation should explain all.

Comment: I couldn't test this, but it sounds reasonable. I ended up refactoring my code so that the two different tasks were generalized into a single function, so I could keep everything in a single queue. Turned out to be a good decision from a code management perspective, as well.

Comment: Make sure to pass queue="red" to apply_sync otherwise, despite this CELERY_ROUTES setting, the task will be sent to the default "celery" queue.
When you use CELERY_ROUTES, I think it's a good idea to also explicit the default CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery' setting (and maybe change it instead of passing the queue information in apply_async).

Comment: @DominiquePERETTI I've never seen that behavior unless you don't reference the task name properly in your `CELERY_ROUTES`.

Answer (score 36):

To link to different queue dynamically, follow the below steps:

1) Specify the name of the queue with the 'queue' attribute

```
celery.send_task('job1', args=[], kwargs={}, queue='queue_name_1')
celery.send_task('job1', args=[], kwargs={}, queue='queue_name_2')
```

(Here a particular job uses two queues)

2) Add the following entry in the configuration file

```
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

3) While starting the worker, use -Q to specify the queue name' from which the jobs to be consumed

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -Q queue1 
celery -A proj worker -l info -Q queue2
```