# python celery multi unregistred task

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two queues in Celery and one tasks.py with tasks. 
When I run celery with

```
celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages1
celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages2
```

in two different terminals, it works fine and run all my tasks.

But if I run in with

```
celery multi start 2 -Q:1 messages1 -Q:2 messages2 --loglevel=DEBUG
```

I get `[2014-05-08 15:30:33,020: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type`.
What I`m doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I've found, that

```
 celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages1
 celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages2
```

actualy runs one worker. When I specify -n param to each worker:

```
 celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages1 -n w1
 celery worker -A myapp  -l info -Q messages2 -n w2
```

I have the same problem:

```
[2014-05-08 16:51:05,329: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type
```

**Update 1:**
 I've already have the following line:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {'messages.tasks.send_message': {'queue': 'message_send'}, 'messages.tasks.control_message_send': {'queue': 'message_manager'}}.
```

Seems there is no effect. And I run task like this:

```
result = send_message.apply_async(('number', 'message text'), queue='message_send').
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? On what platform are you running the worker?

Comment: I need to run two queues and two workers -  one on each. Platform is Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: try running with --loglevel=DEBUG, this could be a syntax error or something missing in PYTHONPATH or you didn't import the tasks on your myapp.py, try running one worker, it should prints the registered tasks

Comment: Maybe try applying this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21328806/2173793? It would, I think, solve you problem.

Comment: When I run one worker, it shows me my tasks as registred. And if I run  `celery multi` with --loglevel=DEBUG, in log file I have the same error: `[2014-05-08 17:19:42,200: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'myapp.messages.tasks.send_message'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.`

Comment: @Renier I've already have the following line: `CELERY_ROUTES = {'messages.tasks.send_message': {'queue': 'message_send'},
                 'messages.tasks.control_message_send': {'queue': 'message_manager'}}`. Seems there is no effect. And I run task like this: `result = send_message.apply_async(('number', 'message text'), queue='message_send')`.

Comment: I've updated the post to make it easier to read code from my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with two steps:

1) Correct run string for celery multi was `celery multi start 2 -Q:1 messages1 -Q:2 messages2 --loglevel=DEBUG -A myapp`

2) I forgot to import my app in the `__init__.py`:

```
`from __future__ import absolute_import
from myapp.celery_app import celery_app as celery_app`
```

And this link from the log message is realy useful. http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-names