# Understanding difference between celery and celery milti?

Tags: python, django, celery

When I run Celery with one worker with `celery worker -A myapp  -l info`, everything is fine, tasks are performed.

But when I run `celery multi start 2 -Q:1 message_send -Q:2 message_manager` in the same directory, I get the '**Received unregistered task**' error. 
How Celery discovers tasks when I run two workers?

My celery.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import absolute_import    
import os    
from celery import Celery   
from django.conf import settings    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings.local')

my_app = Myapp('Myapp', include=['myapp.messages.tasks'])

my_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

my_app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@my_app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

My settings:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {'messages.tasks.send_message': {'queue': 'message_send'},
                 'messages.tasks.control_message_send': {'queue': 'message_manager'}}
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('messages.tasks')
```

My project structure:

```
myapp
    --settings
    --messages
    |  --fixtures
    |  --migrations
    |  --tests
    |    -- __init__.py
    |    -- api.py
    |    -- tasks.py
    |    -- models.py
    |    -- views.py
    -- __init__.py
    -- celery.py
    -- urls.py
    -- utils.py
```

**UPDATE**: The problem was in imports. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23604197/1858864

Answer (score 2):

If you are using celery with django it's better to use manage.py to start celery workers. There are preinstalled commands witch come with celery(or django-celery)

```
# (just one worker)
python manage.py celeryd -Q myqueue -E -l info

# two workers
python manage.py celeryd_multi 1 2 -Q:1 message_send -Q:2 message_manager
```

But if don't want to use django commands you should start celery multi with named workers like this.

```
celery multi start 1 2 -Q:1 message_send -Q:2 message_manager
```

where 1 and 2 are workers.

for more info user `celery multi --help`

Comment: Thank! The problem was in imports and and celery run string.