# Everytime Celery is restarted all the scheduled tasks are acknowledged

Tags: python, django, server, celery

Everytime Celery is restarted all the scheduled tasks are acknowledged again.

And this is leading to a huge time lag to start processing new tasks.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Hello from 2023, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply purge all the tasks before starting Celery again:

```
$ celery purge
WARNING: This will remove all tasks from queue: celery.
         There is no undo for this operation!

(to skip this prompt use the -f option)

Are you sure you want to delete all tasks (yes/NO)?
```

Comment: No, I dont want to purge the tasks. i just the celery to reload the new code without reloading all the tasks

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't want to purge** the tasks which were in the QUEUE waiting to be executed i.e., you also want them to execute, then obviously those **old tasks** will be executed **before the new tasks** as the new tasks came in the QUEUE after the old ones AND because it is a QUEUE, it will follow **First In First Out**.

Now, if you want the ***old tasks to execute*** but ***don't want to wait*** for the old ones to execute first, from what I comprehend by you not wanting to PURGE the old ones and also not wanting the delay, then you can maintain **two or more separate queues** for the tasks.

Hence on every reload, your new tasks will be assigned to a new QUEUE, which won't be dependent on the Old tasks.

See this -> [How to keep multiple independent celery queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853378/how-to-keep-multiple-independent-celery-queues)