# Celery redis queue issue

Tags: python, redis, celery

So I am using Celery and Redis as broker. Here is my configuration file

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1000
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True


CELERY_SEND_TASK_SENT_EVENT = True
CELERYD_SEND_EVENTS = True


_QS = {
    'get_queue': 'get_task',
    'put_queue': 'put_task',
    'post_queue': 'post_task',
    'delete_queue': 'delete_task'
}


CELERY_QUEUES = [
     Queue(name=key, routing_key=value) for key, value in 
     _QS.iteritems()
]

CELERY_ROUTES = {
     value: dict(queue=key) for key, value in _QS.iteritems()
}
```

The idea is to have a separate queue for a HTTP verb. Now I start the Celery worker and head over to redis terminal since I want to see the length of each queue.

Initially when the worker starts and no tasks have been queued , the redis-cli keys give this

```
 1) "celery"
 2) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
 3) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
 4) "_kombu.binding.celery"
```

Now I add some put and get tasks(tasks that are to be enqueued into put_queue and get_queue respectively). The result redis-cli keys gives me this know

```
 1) "celery"
 2) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
 3) "unacked"
 4) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
 5) "unacked_index"
 6) "_kombu.binding.celery"
```

There are no queues named 'get_queue' and put_queue. We have 2 new queues named unacked and unacked_index. Why so? I am trying to have different workers consume from different named queues. But since queues with name specified in configuration file are never created , I am unable to do this. What is going on here guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924975/5012700 Hope it might help.