# Running two celery workers in a server for two django application

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have a server in which two django application are running appone, apptwo
for them, two celery workers are started with commands:

```
celery worker -A appone -B --loglevel=INFO


celery worker -A apptwo -B --loglevel=INFO
```

Both points to same BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'

redis is setup with db 0 and 1

I can see the task configured in these two apps in both app's log, which is leading to warnings and errors.

Can we configure in django settings such that the celery works exclusively without interfering with each other's tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [route tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to different queues. Start Celery with two different `-Q myqueueX` and then use different `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` in your two Django projects.

Depending on your Celery configuration, your Django setting should look something like:

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'myqueue1'
```

You can also have more fine grained control with:

```
@celery.task(queue="myqueue3")
def some_task(...):
  pass
```

More  options here:

[How to keep multiple independent celery queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19853378/492773)